# RestAPI response is not same as Postman Response

Tags: swift, postman, alamofire

I am facing a very strange issue while calling RESTful API. I have a login API, I tested it in Postman and it's working perfectly fine. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

But once I call it using Alamofire, I get the response as `"status :" 1` and `"message" : 'Incorrect Credentials'` It's the same email and password that I'm using in postman but still I get this response even though my email and password is correct. I have tested it on multiple email and passwords, and for every user it gives me same error.

Here is my login Function..

```
 public func login(email: String, password: String, success: @escaping (UserData) -> (), failure: errorClosure)
    {
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "email": "\(email)",
            "password": "\(password)"
        ]
        session.request(Config.loginURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON
            { response in
            switch response.result
            {
            case .success(_):
                let json = response.value
                print("JSON: \(json ?? "errr")")
                MappingHelper.ModelFromResponse(UserData.self, response: response, success: { (result) in
                    success(result)
                }, failure: failure)
            case .failure(let error):
                failure?(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how i'm calling it..

```
helper.login(email: email, password: password) { (UserData) in
            print(UserData)
        } failure: { (error) in
            print(error)
 }
```

Debugging..

[image]

[image]

The reason I am using `session.request` instead of `AF.request` is because when I use AF.request it throws me a certificate error.

> The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be "DOMAIN NAME" which could put your confidential information at risk.

So to bypass this error I created a session with the help of some answer from SO.

```
private let session: Session = {
        let manager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: ["******.com": DisabledTrustEvaluator()])
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
        return Session(configuration: configuration, serverTrustManager: manager)
    }()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is `JSONEncoding.default` because you don't want to send a JSON body according to your Postman screenshot. You'll want to use a url-form-encoded as defined [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#post-request-with-url-encoded-parameters)

Comment: okay let me go through it. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: OMG! It worked! Thank you so much @Leslie Alldridge. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, I've never written swift or used this library before but I have read a lot of technical documentation for various API libraries :) glad it helped!

Comment: Yes it did :D Thanks again! Cheers.